# why do meld shows all files in my git branch as unversioned?

Tags: git, meld

I have freshly, locally cloned git branch.
When I start meld and choose "version control view" it unfortunately shows all my files, including ".git" with all its contents, as unversioned.
Why does it happen?
The OS is windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a small investigation I've found that git have to be installed with access from windows command prompt (in addition to default git bash).
Maybe this answer will be useful for someone.